# Многоуровневая связь в таблице

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

В чём заключается моя задача. У меня есть интернет магазин(на Laravel) в котором есть категории и подкатегории, в моём случае это группы. Что я хочу сделать и какие мои идеи? Мне нужно сделать много уровневое меню в которое входят категории, группы и произвольные ссылки, как я думал сделать по самой структуре таблице:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('target_id');
        $table->string('instance', 32);
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id');
        $table->foreign('parent_id')->references('id')->on('menu');
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
target_id - это айдишник в который может быть либо категории либо подгруппы либо таблицы с произвольными ссылками
instance - собственно сама таблица из приведённых выше
```

Что я хотел, нормальный такой вариант, или есть более лучше вариант, просто при запросе этого меню можно ногу сломать.
Благодарю за любой ваш ответ и помощь

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, таблицы надо стараться держать нормализованными. Связывать таблицы между собой и так далее. Однако создавать на каждую мелкую таблицу (которая не является сущностью сама по себе) модель - такая идея мне не нравится.

Ну и я организовал работу так: для больших сущностей, т.е. каких-то основных объектов проекта (например пользователи, сообщения, посты) я создаю модели, и репозитории под них. Однако репозиторий может обращаться и к другим мелим таблицам, у которых нет своих моделей и репозиториев. Например, у Вас есть категория, которая описывается чем-то. Соответственно у товара можно сделать столбец  "category_id" который будет ссылаться на категории. Однако для хорошей нормализированной базы нужно много мелких вспомогательных таблиц, и как я говорил, делать под каждую модель и репозиторий на мой взгляд нет смысла, а значит прописывать отношения из Eloquent надо вручную в репозитории.
Например: в репозитории "товар" должен быть такой метод:

```
public static function getProductCategory($category_id)
{
    return DB::table('categories')->where('id', $category_id)->first();
}
```

Я считаю что писать сырые запросы в репозиториях это хорошая практика, если под них нет своей модели. А создавать отдельные модели и репозитории под каждую таблицу с парой методов get() смысла нет. Также я делю репозитории на read и write потому что они сильно отличаются. У read реп-в не должны быть свойства вообще (т.к. они не должны хранить сущность, у себя, это делает БД). И соответственно все методы делать статическими чтобы свободно обращаться к ним из других репозиториев. А у write реп-в должно быть свойство, хранящее модель. Ну и самое важное, все специфичные запросы выносить в методы реп-в, повторяющиеся, такие как Where('is_admin', 1) выносить в scopes. Там где можно, в моделях прописывать отношения. Где нельзя - вручную в реп-ах.